# Metasploit does't detect added exploit from exploit-db

Tags: python, exploit, metasploit

I've added an exploit from www.exploit-db.com to `/.msf4/modules/exploit/windows/remote/41987.py` following the naming convention. I updated the database with the command `updatedb` and rebooted.

Metasploit does not detect the newly added exploit. However, if i add `41891.rb`, it detects it no problem.  Why does Metasploit not see the python files?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

Metasploit has feature to import python modules but it cannot work with any random python script, that script needs a structure to be working in Metasploit.

You will get a detailed view in this answer. A very informative one.

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/196730/metasploit-is-not-detecting-newly-imported-python-exploit

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Because metasploit is purely written in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

DO as follow to add python extension (if you havent done yet):
- meterpreter > use python
- try python_import to import your python code module

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little script a few months to fix **import a custom module to metasploit**. Here's the link **https://github.com/donovandevs/fixs**
It was impossible reload or update the msf exploits after import a custom module.
And it gives me a huge random error related with the **stack**, but that wasn't possible.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)